# Не могу понять почему Python 0.33÷11 получает 0.030000000000000002

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=0.33/11
print(a)
#это в пудроид 3
```

Comment: А что не так? Нормальное представление компьютера числа с плавающей точкой

Comment: Для развлечения посмотрите на результат print(0.1*3)

Comment: @Валентин, коллеги по цену хотят подсказать вам посмотреть в направлении используемого в современных системах стандарта (IEEE 754) работы с числами с плавающей точкой (например, [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/)), который, как бы, является компромиссом между точностью хранения, объемом занимаемой памяти и скорости выполнения операций с числами в данном представлении.